# Trying to create login page but I cant figure out how to navigate pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm strugling to figure out how to navigate pages. Currently When I press a button it opens a new Blank page not the page I want. Or I get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.'

I'm trying to get it so when a user clicks the buttons it sends them to a new page. I would really appreacite any help I can get on this.`

XAML(This isnt the Whole code Btw. I just took the parts I thought were important)

```
<Window x:Class="Movie_Appp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Movie_Appp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Main"
        Height="450" 
        Width="800"
        Name="Main"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown">
<Button x:Name="BtnLogin" 
      BorderThickness="0"
      Content="Login"
      Foreground="White"
      FontSize="12"
      FontFamily="Montserrat"
      Cursor="Hand"
      Click="BtnLogin_Click"
      Margin="0, 15,0,0">

  <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#462AD8"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#28AEED"/>
              </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
  </Button.Style>

  <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Border Width="150" Height="40"
                  CornerRadius="20"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
              <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
          </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

C#

```
using Movie_Appp.View;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Movie_Appp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of LoginView
            LoginView loginView = new LoginView();

            // Show the new window
            loginView.Show();
        }

        private void BtnSignUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of SignUpView
            SignUpView signUpView = new SignUpView();

            // Show the new window
            signUpView.Show();
        }




        private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DragMove();
            }
        }

        private void btnMinimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }


        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your project doesn't seem to be using WPF XAML Pages - instead you have a `Window` there. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: I think it would make very much sense to post the code that produces the error. Not sur ewhy you thonk that your posted code is creating any errors. You basically only  show the  template of a Button and the invokation of a Show method. We can only assume that this could be the WindowShow method but it could be anything. Please update your code to provide a version that produces the error you are encountering. Also clarify what kind of navigation do you want. Do you want to show multiple screens by showing individuak Window instances or do you want a single-page application?

Comment: I can only guess that the problem is in one of the views that you haven't shown to us (you didn't even tell which view is the problematic one). [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A page must exist within a host element like a 'Frame' in order utilise page navigation with a window.

You will need a to have a frame inside the window and pages to navigate to. The structure is
Window
-Frame
--Pages

In the XAML define a Frame element in the window. Define the x:Name="" property.

In the codebehind set the frame.content to an instance of the page you want to display.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
//initialize page variables to hold instances
    private Page1 firstpage;
    private Page2 page2;
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
//create instance of a page
        page1 = new Page1();
//set frame element defined in XAML content to initialized page
        frame_element_name.Content = Page1;
        firstpage = frame_element_name.Content as Page1;
        
    }


    private void button_click(object sender, e eventargs)
    {
//initialize new page 
        Page2 newpage = new Page2(); //newpage_X if subseuent instance of same page
 // or page2 = oldpage; // or pagewhateverpage_X etc...


frame_element_name.Content = page2; // or = pagewhateverpage_X
    }

    private void other_methods(...)
    {
    //to access it elsewhere after initialised and navigated away from, refer to to the frames previous content rather than a new instance of page to retrieve in the state or just ensure the frame Navigation is set to visible and the frames Navigation Journal is caching the navigation Journal Entries and/or Forward/Back stack items
        if(page_name!=null)
        {
            frame_elemnet_name.Content = page_name;
//or frame_element_name.Navigate(initialized and previously displayed page);
        }
    else if (page_name == null)
    {
        frame.Content = new Pagenametype();
        pagename = frame_element_name.Content as Pagenametype;
     }
 }
```

}